# If I revok iOS distribution will stop APNS on live app?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

If I revoke iOS distribution certificate then will it stop push notification on live app?

Should I have to regenerate new APNS certificate from developer.apple.com?

Comment: I think yes. I got the same problem when i transfer app to another account.

Comment: You're completely right, here's link to official documentation. https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expired or Revoked Certificates :

**Apple Push Notification Service Certificate**

> You can no longer send push notifications to your app.

Source :  [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/)

Comment: Correct. I Revoked and generate new iOS distribution certificate and checked for push notification, but push notification was not working. I generate APNS certificate again and uploaded new .p12 to server and push notification works fine now.